# Which of these MS products can I remove from my computer (in Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, sdk, windows-10

I have many Microsoft softwares present in my installed programs list. I had once installed MS Visual Studio 2015 and then 2017 also and while I did that, I had installed many extra utilities that came with it. I have a feeling I only uninstalled Visual Studio later and did not uninstall those utilities and now they are using up space for no reason. I checked for these online but nowhere could I find anything specific. I need to know if the softwares/programs in this list can be removed without creating issues in my laptop. I am using Windows 10 on an HP laptop. I'll be thankful for any help received.

- I still have MS VS Code installed though.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT: I don't have any software that uses these packages/software, but I don't know if these are used by the OS itself or not (or some software that comes pre-installed with Windows10) (some of these softwares/packages come pre-installed in Windows 10)

Comment: We cannot answer that question. Whether uninstalling any given package creates issues for you is something only you can verify. If you are uninstalling a package you are using this will create issues. We don't know whether you are using any given package.

Comment: *"I don't have any software that uses these packages/software"* - I doubt that to be accurate. It's a reasonable assumption that at least some programs rely on the C++ support libraries being installed into the default location.

Comment: remove the 2.1.5xx SDKs and only keep the one which highest number. The c++ redists shouldn't be removed we don't know which software you have that uses them.